# AT91SAM7X512 reset type issue

Tags: embedded, arm, microcontroller, reset, atmel

I am using an AT91SAM7X512 for my application. I perform a software reset after certain action. The processor resets. But upon reading the `RSTC_RSR` status register I get an invalid register value for the reset type: `RSTC_RSR = 0x700` which translates the `RSTTYP` register value to be `111` . This condition is not defined in the data sheet. I am reading the reset type by using the statement `unsigned int buffer = AT91C_RSTC_RSTTYP;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AT91C_RSTC_RSTTYP` is the constant `0x700`, it is the bitmask to mask out the `RSTTYP` bits in the `RSTC_SR` register (defined in `AT91SAM7X512.h`):

```
#define AT91C_RSTC_RSTTYP     (0x7 <<  8) // (RSTC) Reset Type
```

To read the register there is a pointer `AT91C_RSTC_RSR`:

```
#define AT91C_RSTC_RSR  (AT91_CAST(AT91_REG *)  0xFFFFFD04) // (RSTC) Reset Status Register
```

So

```
unsigned int buffer = *AT91C_RSTC_RSR;
```

should work for reading the register (but I didn't test it).

Comment: I'm novice to stackoverflow. Learning the nitty gritty. 
Thanks for asking. I've up voted it now.